# Failed to read the uploaded file using inputstream jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, file-upload, zip

I am trying to upload a file from jsp page. I am successful to get all the fields from the jsp file but can able to read the file which i get uploaded in the jsp. I am uploading a zip file from the jsp page. here is my code.

```
 ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
 FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(req);
while (iter.hasNext()) {
            FileItemStream item = iter.next();
            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                String name = item.getFieldName();
                System.out.println("File field " + name + " with file name " + item.getName() + " detected.");
                InputStream stream = item.openStream();
                BuildVO buildVO = buildDAO.findByFileName(item.getName());
                ZipEntry entry;
                ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(stream);
                while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null ) {
                    System.out.println(buildVO.getOriginalFileName()+">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>fileFound??????"+entry.getName());
                }
             }
          }
```

with this code i get the input stream of a uploaded file. But from that i cannot able to read the zip file and it contents.Any one can help me?

Comment: is your form like this `<form action="UploadServlet" method="post"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: What is the error/problem?

Comment: Check this link : [Handling images/files in ADF](http://tompeez.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/jdev11-1-2-1-0-handling-imagesfiles-in-adf-part-3/) Although it is developed in `ADF` framework. But still it is using `Servlet`

Comment: yes  I wish I could think of a good

Comment: there is no error. i am getting null in the getNextEntry() Mr. Erwin